# rails の devise でパスワードの復号化はできる?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

rails でパスワード認証を実装する場合には、 devise が一般的に使われる、という理解をしています。

ふと devise の仕様について気になったのですが、 devise でテーブルに保存されたパスワード情報を使って、元の生パスワードを復元することはできますか？(devise の暗号化は、可逆ですか？)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デフォルトのdeviseのパスワード暗号は不可逆です。
暗号化にはBcryptといういのが使われています。
一般に忘れてしまったパスワードはパスワードリセットメールを送り、再設定させますね。

安全性が気になるところではありますが、以下のような復号化ができるdeviseのエクステンションgemはあります。
https://github.com/chicks/devise_aes_encryptable

こちらはAESが使われています。
ただ、他のところでも言われていますが、パスワードは復号化できない方がセキュリティ的にはベターです。